# Change multiple properties of an object in one command

Tags: c#

Here is an object with three properties:

```
public class myClass
{
   public int score { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public bool isAlive { get; set; }
}
```

after creating an instance of this class, in some places, I'm changing two or three properties of this instance like this:

```
targetInstance.score = 1;
targetInstance.name = "John";
targetInstance.isAlive = true;
```

is there any way to use `targetInstance` once and then in a way using some brackets just sets the properties (like initialization), something similar to this:

```
targetInstance = { score = 1, name = "John" }
```

Note: maybe you suggest to have a method which takes these and change the properties, but it is not suitable while there are so many properties.

Comment: Do you mean you want your changes to a given instance reflected everywhere? Maybe try a singleton pattern

Answer (score 7):

### Named parameters

You could write a method with named, default parameters, and use named arguments to update only the ones you want.

For example:

```
public class myClass
{
   public int score { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public bool isAlive { get; set; }

   public void Set(int score = -1, string name = null, bool? isAlive = null)
   {
       if (score != -1) this.score = score;
       if (name != null) this.name = name;
       if (isAlive.HasValue) this.isAlive = isAlive.Value;
   }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
var o = new myClass();
o.Set(name: "Hello");
```

Or

```
var o = new myClass();
o.Set(name: "Hello", isValid: false);
```

Or

```
var o = new myClass();
o.Set(score: 100, isValid: false);
```

### Fluent syntax

You can create a set of "setter methods" that are chainable, like so:

```
public class myClass
{
   public int score { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public bool isAlive { get; set; }

   public myClass SetScore(int score)
   {
       this.score = score;
       return this;
   }

   public myClass SetName(string name)
   {
       this.name = name;
       return this;
   }

   public myClass SetIsAlive(bool isAlive)
   {
       this.isAlive = isAlive;
       return this;
   }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var o = new myClass();
o.SetName("Donald").SetIsAlive(true);
```

Or like this:

```
var o = new myClass()
    .SetName("Bob")
    .SetScore(0)
    .SetIsAlive(true);
```

Comment: You can use `int?` instead of relying on `-1`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei True. But what will you use if you have `int?` property :)

Comment: @IvanStoev The only effective approach to distinguish between 'passing default value' or 'not passing a value' for an optional parameter is avoid using optional parameter and use different overloads (which doesn't worth it in this case IMO).

Answer (score 5):

The closest is using C# 7 [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples) deconstruction syntax:

```
(targetInstance.score, targetInstance.name, targetInstance.isAlive) = (1, "John", true);
```

It still requires repeating target variable name though, so Daniel Hilgarth answer is the correct one.

Comment: He doesn't want to write `targetInstance.` multiple times

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Ah, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for an equivalent for the [`With`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) keyword in VB.
In C#, there is none.

Answer (score 2):

As an option you can create a `With` extension method:

```
public static class WithExtension
{
    public static void With<T>(this T o, Action<T> values)
    {
        values?.Invoke(o);
    }
}
```

Then use it this way:

```
person.With(p=>{
    p.Id = 1;
    p.Name = "Someone";
    p.BirthDate = DateTime.Now;
});
```

---

Another option:

```
public static class WithExtension
{
    public static void With(this object o, object values)
    {
        var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(values);
        var sourceProps = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(o);
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor p in props)
        {
            sourceProps[p.Name].SetValue(o, p.GetValue(values));
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
person.With(new {Id = 1, Name = "Someone", BirthDate = DateTime.Now});
```

But be aware that you are relying on type description (or reflection by your choice) and mistakes in property names can be discovered only at run-time.

Comment: This just replaces `person` with `p` (still need to repeat the variable name even if it short). Not counting the delegate overhead and potential closure introduction.

Comment: @IvanStoev I agree. Just shared something for those who are looking for something a bit similar to `With` in VB. But in general, I'd probably suggest a function, or nothing but writing it manually as a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a copy constructor in conjunction with object initialization, either new up an entirely new object when you want to modify the old one or overwrite the old one with the new one. Something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person() // this is your default constructor
    {
    }

    public Person(Person originalPerson) // this is your copy constructor
    {
        Name = originalPerson.Name;
        Surname = originalPerson.Surname;
        Address = originalPerson.Address;
        Age = originalPerson.Age;
    }

    public string Name;
    public string Surname;
    public string Address;
    public int Age;
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // create object with whatever properties you like
        var person1 = new Person
        {
            Name = "Max", Surname = "Mustermann", Age = 30,
        };

        // now rewrite the old object with the old properties and modify
        // any properties you like using object initialization
        person1 = new Person(person1)
        {
            Address = "Main Street 1",
            Age = 32,
        };

        // now person1 has the Name, Surname from 1st assignment
        // plus Address and Age from 2nd assignment (Age = 32)
    }
}
```

Comment: You forget to give equal to sign after Age

Answer (score 1):

you could use `Reflection` (add `using System.Reflection;` in your class code) and add a proper method to `myClass`:

```
    public void SetProperties(params object[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Count(); i += 2)
        {
            PropertyInfo myProp = this.GetType().GetProperty(args[i].ToString());
            myProp.SetValue(this, args[i + 1]);
        }
    }
```

that you could use in you code as follows:

```
targetInstance.SetProperties("score", 1, "name", "John", "isAlive", true);

targetInstance.SetProperties("isAlive", true, "score", 1);

targetInstance.SetProperties("name", "John", "isAlive", true);
```

and so on...

you may want to enhance `SetProperties()` with Try/Catch blocks to check for misspelled property names or values type